# Plot bar in matlab with log-scale x axis and same width

Tags: matlab, plot

I want to plot a bar chart in Matlab with (1) log-scale for x-axis and (2)bars in same width. But with the code below, the width of the bars are different. Can any one help? Many thanks！

```
    xdata = [0.01 0.018 0.032 0.056 0.1 0.18 0.32 0.56 1 1.8 3.2 5.6 10];
    ydata = [1.3 1.6 1.5 1.2 1.0 3.5 0.6 3.1 1.6 1.9 1.7 0.3 0.4];
    bar(xdata,ydata);
    set(gca,'XScale','log');
```

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Instead of plotting `xdata` on a log scale, plot the log of `xdata` on a linear scale. Then modify labels to reflect the linear value (not the used log value).

```
xdata = [0.01 0.018 0.032 0.056 0.1 0.18 0.32 0.56 1 1.8 3.2 5.6 10];
ydata = [1.3 1.6 1.5 1.2 1.0 3.5 0.6 3.1 1.6 1.9 1.7 0.3 0.4];
bar(log10(xdata),ydata);
set(gca,'Xtick',-3:1); %// adjust manually; values in log scale
set(gca,'Xticklabel',10.^get(gca,'Xtick')); %// use labels with linear values
```

[image]

Comment: Really really clever :)